# Shared Hosting on Exchange 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, hosting, exchange-2003

Our company is a web development company that host several websites for various clients. We are a smaller company, in fact approximately 10 employees. All employees are on a network and have associated emails through a windows 2003 exchange server. Recently, one of our employers promised a client that we would be able to host their email on our exchange server. Not my idea of a fun project. I have no other means of hosting their email, it must reside on our exchange server and separate from our employee's emails as well.

We basically need to host their email on our server. I have been told that there is the capability of this set up in the core of MS Exchange but lack the knowledge on how to do this. Do I have to set up a new domain for the clients so that it wont be under our domain? I also need to make sure the following criteria is met...

1. Hosted email
2. Web Access Email
3. Mobile access to email (on supported device)

Does meeting these needs then push me into the area of POP3? If so how can I take care of this at the same time? Can anyone help me figure out how to accomplish this in MS Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting with Exchange Server 2003 is fairly straight forward once you understand what needs to be done and why. This guide is a great primer on setting it up.

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Shared_Hosting_Exchange_2003_Part1.html

Comment: I gave this a shot, however in the pictures on this guide, it shows a **Hosting** folder under the hosting.farm domain. I can't figure out how to set that up and when I add the security group they are applied under the company domain. Any ideas?

Comment: That's an Organizational Unit in ADUC, not a folder in ESM. You'll create an OU for the "hosted" company's users and groups.